# Specifying periodic time intervals (eg: operating hours of an office)

Tags: time

I am designing an API where I need to specify the operating hours of an office. It could be like

- 0815-1745 every Monday to Friday
- Every Second Saturday
- On expected rush days till 2000 [eg: 2021-06-15 1745-2000]

Each interval will be specified separately and the final operating hours will be the sum of all the individual intervals.

I need a means to specify this succinctly. There are two existing choices I am aware of:

1. Extended `cron` format as defined in https://crontab.guru/
2. Asterisk `GotoIfTime` syntax: https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-cmd-gotoiftime

The cron syntax is not really able to defined ranges like 0815-1745 every Monday to Friday, but the Asterisk syntax is quite capable.

Does any other [better?] syntax/means exists which can achieve the same result? A library to do so will be mighty cool.

Comment: Things like "every second Saturday" may be problematic. Because somehow you need to define what's the "first" and what's the "second" Saturday ...

Comment: These are quite common, for example Indian Banks work every first, third and fifth(if present) Saturdays :)